# How can I select a link using d3.select?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have a React component containing a graph built in react-d3-graph and am trying to select a link between nodes when the link is clicked on, but I cannot figure out the correct way to target it. I am able to target an individual node with the following script:

```
d3.select("#graph-id-graph-wrapper").selectAll("g#graph-id-graph-container-
```

zoomable").selectAll("g[id='" + source + 
    "']").selectAll("path").attr('fill',"red").attr('opacity',"1")

graph-id-graph-wrapper is the top div, graph-id-graph-container-zoomable is the child div, the nodes are referenced as g in the layout with an ID, and the path is the actual rectangular node symbol. The links are paths with no ID (children of the node paths), which look like this in the code:

```
<path cursor="pointer" opacity="1" d="M-10.606601717798213,-10.606601717798213h21.213203435596427v21.213203435596427h-21.213203435596427Z" fill="#57a3ff" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.5" class=""></path>
```

I have tried a zillion variations of d3.select(this) and nothing is working. The nodes were easier to target because they have an ID, but the link path does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to select that specify path, you can always use a custom pattern, d3 selector use DOM querySelector function, see [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/select.js#L3)

If you have your nodes and links without ids, maybe you can find some unique attribute that works for nodes but not for links, for example, if the node has the attribute **cursor** you can select all paths with it

```
d3.selectAll('path[cursor]')
```

If you want only the links, maybe then don't have **cursor** attribute then you can try

```
d3.selectAll('path:not([cursor])')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So if the d3.selectAll('path[cursor]') and gets me a list of links, how do I target a SPECIFIC link. Like d3.select(this)? I am able to get a full list of the ".path" links but can't specify beyond that. I have actually got this within a click function that is trying to target an individual link based on starting point and end point variables.

Comment: If you have a specific event target event on the path, you can select it like this d3.selectAll('path[cursor]').on('click', () => console.log(d3.select(d3.event.target))), using d3.select(d3.event.target)

Comment: Thank you I will definitely try this!